# JavaScript problems when launching site in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, flash, iframe

I have set up an Articulate Storyline course (a Flash version accessed using the page "story.html" and an HTML5 version accessed using "story_html5.html"). It works fine when run directly, however, when I try to run everything in an iframe on the company server (linking to the course files on my personal server) I get JavaScript errors:

The course uses `player.GetVar("HTML5spelaren")` to access a variable called `HTML5spelaren`, which is located on the story_html5.html page itself. When running in an iframe I get a "Permission denied to access property 'HTML5spelaren'".

Finally the course uses the JavaScript `var newWin=document.window.open("report.html", "Kursintyg");` to display a course completion certificate in a new window. When running in an iframe however this results in a "Permission denied to access property 'open'".

Is there a way to rewrite the JavaScripts to get around this? I need to be able to detect if the course is running in Flash or HTML5 mode (that's what I use the variable in story_html5.html for), as well as being able to use JavaScript to open a new page from within the iframe when clicking on a link.

Page structure:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11131031/pagestructure.png

/Andreas

Answer (score 1):

There's a way for different domains to speak to one another via javascript. You can use postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

In your case, in story.html or story_html5.html could use something like:

```
parent.postMessage(HTML5spelaren, parent_domain);
```

and you add an event listener in the company page:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

And in receiveMessage function you retrieve the data that you need. Something like:

```
function receiveMessage(event){
    your_variable = event.data
}
```

Same logic can be probably be applied to your popup.

You can post from child to parent or from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that content you're linking to in the iFrame is on a different server/domain. If so, the error is a security feature to stop cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Consider putting both the parent iFrame and the articulate content (child) on the same server. This should eliminate the problem.